# doesn't find messages_XX.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, multilingual

I have an application rest in springboot and I need multi-languages. The application finds messages.properties but not messages_es.properties.

My code:
In application.properties

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

In controller

```
messageSource.getMessage("message.forgotSubject", null, new Locale(lang))
```

if lang is es it’s the same.
If I remove messages.properties, error is No message found under code

> 'message.forgotSubject' for locale 'es'.",

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You set spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages, so your multi-language properties file must base messages.properties, if you remove this file, the basename should be i18n/messages_es. But if you do this, the file suffix es is not a language but apart of the file name.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot put i18n/messages_es because I am going to have others languages as messages_fr or messages_en. I must find a method that allows to work with any language and also messages.properties if the language doesn't exist.

Comment: When your JVM locale equals to the locale you set, the message.properties will take precedence. Don't remove messages.properties and set the content same as message_es.properties.

Comment: But messages_es.properties is never read even if I put local 'es'. messages.properties will be the default language.

Comment: When you deploy your app at a JVM which locale is not "es" then the messages_es.properties is worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
It’s not in application.properties.  I have done

```
@Configuration
public class CustomLocaleResolver {
   @Bean
   public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    rs.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return rs;
  }
}
```

And I use

```
@Autowired   
private MessageSource messageSource;

messageSource.getMessage("message.salutation", null, new Locale(lang)
```

Thanks